# Processing: Multiscreens and fps

Tags: performance, processing, resolution, frame-rate, multiscreen

I am developing a processing program that uses 12 full HD screens aiming to display a 7680x3240 video, but I am seeing that the performance is really bad, as I am getting something between 7 and 9 fps when playing those videos.

Testing with a lower resolution like 2000 x 3240 I am getting values between 65 and 100 fps, and with a medium resolution of 4000 x 3240 I am getting values between 12 and 14 fps.

As technical details, I am using two AMD FireProW600 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, with crossfire deactivated to enable the use of Xinerama.

I can see there's a huge gap in performance. Is there anything that I am missing to improve the fps when using all the screens?

Comment: Are you rendering this on a single machine or on multiple machines networked ?

Comment: Just using one machine, although I have seen that most projects made in Processing use several machines to display that many pixels.

Comment: Crossposted: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/9360/multiscreens-and-fps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing uses a single thread to do all the rendering and event stuff.

You could try multi-threading anything you can. Or more likely, you'd be better off having different Processing sketches for each screen- maybe connected by a Java program for communication between them.

Comment: Will keep in mind that I need to multi-thread all my future program features in Processing, although right now I am just trying to figure out how to reduce the fps when going full screen in my environment. Thanks!

Comment: You can't just multithread arbitrary aspects of rendering. Processing uses a single-threaded model, for good reasons. You're probably better off splitting it up into multiple Processing sketches, then doing the communication via a Java application.

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple machines I recommend using [Daniel Shiffman's Most Pixels Ever](https://github.com/shiffman/Most-Pixels-Ever-Processing) project and for a single computer, multiple screens scenario have a look at Texas Advanced Computing Center from UT Austin's [MassivePixelEnvironment](http://tacc.github.io/MassivePixelEnvironment/) library.

You might also want to check how you're generating these 12 HD screens and also, in case they are pre-rendered or even static images, what's the fastest way to display them on your target screen(s)

Comment: I am using Shiffman's MPE to synchronize two computers with the same specs as the one stated in the problem, but before expanding the code, I was trying without interconnecting them to have a faster deployment. I am displaying the video using Processing's core video library, and pretty much using the same code as in the example provided in the API : https://www.processing.org/reference/libraries/video/Movie_play_.html .

I need to have a look at the MassivePixelEnvironment library and check if there's improvement using that. Thanks!